# Show loading circle while doing an operation in os x app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have an OS X application. It has the "Update all" button.
The problem is this "Update all" action takes some time (from 1 second to some minutes, depending on how large is the database). Now, when I press the "Update all" button, my application just freezes for some time, and mouse becomes "spinning rainbow".

I need to make a little spinning circle at the bottom while this application "is thinking", like this:
http://d.pr/i/Cps6+
Looking forward for your answers,
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perform the operation (update all action) in background thread using GCD and use "[NSProgressIndicator](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSProgressIndicator)" to show loading.

here is a snippet for GCD

http://www.asnippet.com/one_snippet.php?command=getSnippet&snippetId=1922

Comment: And do you know where I can get reload and add buttons like on this screenshot?

Comment: create a new question please :-)